# Find a set whose size is $k!{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Can you describe a counting problem where the size of set  is equal to:
$$
k!{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Alice is in a class of $n$ people.  In how many ways may $k$ of the people from the class be lined up for a picture if Alice must be included in the people selected?